# Woocommerce: Extra added country field not taking value from database

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I have created a form as per posted [here](https://support.woothemes.com/hc/en-us/articles/203182373-How-to-add-custom-fields-in-user-registration-on-the-My-Account-page)

Everything is working fine except country field on checkout page.

On checkout page saved value of country isn't getting fetched from database.

Note: default default woocommerce field for country is with drop-down and State/County field gets list of states accordingly.

Code for country field....

```
<p class="form-row form-row-first">
<label for="reg_billing_country"><?php _e( 'Country', 'woocommerce' ); ?> <span class="required">*</span></label>
<input type="text" class="input-text" name="billing_country" id="reg_billing_country" value="<?php if ( ! empty( $_POST['billing_country'] ) ) esc_attr_e( $_POST['billing_country'] ); ?>" />
</p>
```

Validation code....

```
if ( isset( $_POST['billing_country'] ) && empty( $_POST['billing_country'] ) ) {
    $validation_errors->add( 'billing_country_error', __( '<strong>Error</strong>: Country is required!.', 'woocommerce' ) );
}
```

Storing in database....

```
if ( isset( $_POST['billing_country'] ) ) {
    // WooCommerce billing phone
    update_user_meta( $customer_id, 'billing_country', sanitize_text_field( $_POST['billing_country'] ) );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless I'm missing something, you're collecting the data through the post, validating it, and storing it, but I'm not seeing how you intended to display the `billing_country` in the checkout template.

Since the `billing_country` data is stored in the user meta, you could display it in your checkout template using [get_user_meta](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_user_meta):

```
<?php

  $billingCountry = get_user_meta($customer_id, 'billing_country', true);

  echo $billingCountry;

?>
```